# curl equivalent in Java using commons HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, curl, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using Commons HttpClient to send a post request along with some string content as parameter. Following is my code:

```
    // obtain the default httpclient
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // obtain a http post request object
    postRequest = new HttpPost(stanbolInstance);
    postRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    // create an http param containing summary of article
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", content));

    try {
        // add the param to postRequest
        postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // obtain the response
        response = client.execute(postRequest);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here, stanbolInstance is: `http://dev.iks-project.eu:8081/enhancer`
It does not work. Following is the exception:

```
Problem accessing /enhancer. Reason:
<pre>    The parsed byte array MUST NOT be NULL!</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parsed byte array MUST NOT be NULL!
```

Following is the cURL equivalent which works:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: text/turtle" -H "Content-type: text/plain" --data "The Stanbol enhancer can detect famous cities such as Paris and people such as Bob Marley." http://dev.iks-project.eu:8081/enhancer
```

Help!

Comment: Check the contents of 'content'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're putting the content in the wrong way.

Replace:

```
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", content));

    try {
        // add the param to postRequest
        postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

with

```
postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(content));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Actually I followed a tutorial from vogella.com